# load audio file in Meteor app

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3, meteor

I'm just getting started with Meteor and I want to play a static audio file, either MP3 or M4A.  I can't seem to find the right place to put such a file.  I created a public/ directory and put my audio files in there, but then when I try to load `http://localhost:3000/public/myfile.mp3`, it just loads my Meteor home page again (i.e., a regular HTML page, not the audio file).  It's like the server isn't seeing the file.  Is there some way I have to register the file with Meteor, or should it be in a different location?  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, it was there, you just don't access it via `/public/myfile.mp3`, but rather through `/myfile.mp3`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access all public files that way. You can also place files in subfolders. For example if your file is in `./public/mp3z/myfile.mp3` it can be accessed via Meteor like `/mp3z/myfile.mp3`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you put it on public folder you could play that file by adding domain/your.mp3 to your audio src.